# firestore security: exist and get within the same function does not work

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to `get()` a document and then based on the result, to see if another document exists using `exists()`. However, this fails because the variable that should be storing a string remains an object, namely `parentId` below.

**Observed**

It does not convert `parentId` to a string and it fails when calling `exists()`.

```
function validateAuth() {
  let parentId = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/items/$(resource.data.itemId)).data.parentId
  return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/other-items/$(parentId):$(request.auth.uid))
}
```

**Expected**

It should convert `parentId` to a string so that `exists` can be performed.

#### What I've tried

This below works, and the function is able to evaluate when the document ID using `parentId` exists and doesn't exist.

```
function validateAuth() {
//  let parentId = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/items/$(resource.data.itemId)).data.parentId
  let parentId = 'some-id';
  return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/other-items/$(parentId):$(request.auth.uid))
}
```

Now, I removed the string concatenation below but this still throws an error

```
function validateAuth() {
//  let parentId = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/items/$(resource.data.itemId)).data.parentId
  let parentId = 'some-id';
  return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/other-items/$(parentId))
}
```

The below does not work, and the `parentId` is still an object when ran in the simulator.

```
function validateAuth() {
  let parentId = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/items/$(resource.data.itemId)).data.parentId;
  let parentIdStr = string(parentId);
  return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/other-items/$(parentIdStr):$(request.auth.uid))
}
```

#### Error details

I get this error after the console processes it for about 5 ~ 10 seconds, which is a lot longer than if the requests are processed correctly.

```
Error: Invalid argument provided to call. Function: [exists], Argument: ["||invalid_argument||"]
```

[image]

I couldn't find any documentation about this. Does anyone know if this should work or if there are workarounds?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: @JRodDynamite No, I could not find a good resolution. There are two lesser alternatives: 1) make this non-transactional by splitting into two calls 2) duplicate the reference in another model by adding parent state in the child. I think I chose 1).

Answer (score 0):

The part with colon seems to be the problem:

```
$(parentIdStr):$(request.auth.uid)
```

Try refactoring that to a single element in path:

```
$(parentIdStr+':'+request.auth.uid)
```

Comment: If I remove the semicolon and the second variable completely, it still throws an error. I added that case in the question, thanks.

Comment: Can you share the error that you get in rules playground?

Comment: Good point. I added some more details. Thanks!

Comment: Were you by any chance able to take a look at this? I'm still mind-boggled why this doesn't work... it would mean I need to re-populate some parameters in many models...

Comment: @Taku sorry, I somehow missed your notification. Can you share your complete rules? Seems some function is kot defined.